# How to make a scatter plot using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a data vs. Time graph for some Methane emissions data I have. The code so far looks like this:

```
CH4 <- as.numeric(Aeris_2_Data$CH4)
Aeris_2_Data$Date.Time <- as.POSIXct(Aeris_2_Data$Time_Stamp, tz = "", "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")

ggplot(Aeris_2_Data, aes(x = Aeris_2_Data$Date.Time, y = as.numeric(CH4)) + geom_point() + labs(x = "Time", y = "CH4 [ppm]") + ggtitle("Methane Over Time")
```

My data looks like this:

[head(Aeris_2_Data)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkOcr.png) and this: [an extension of head](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BhJ1.png)

I am trying to map CH4 over time as you can probably see from the small code fragment I've managed so far. but I keep getting the error:

```
Error in seq.int(0, to0 - from, by) : 'to' must be a finite number
```

Everything seems to match the ggplot info I remember and also found online. What is going wrong? My guess is to do with the formatting of the time data, which is in the format `%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S`and stored as a character in the csv file I am pulling from. How do I properly format that to change it?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might try replacing `aes(x = Aeris_2_Data$Date.Time, ...)` with `aes(x = Date.Time, ...)`. Also, [please don't post images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11374827) of code or data. To share data, you can copy-paste the output of `dput(my_example_data)`.

Answer (score 1):

There are two errors in your code :

- date format is `"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"` and not `"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"`
- one `)` is missing after `aes()`

Additionnaly as mentioned is the comments you should better use `Date.Time` and transform `CH4` as numeric directly into the data.frame

The code should be:

```
Aeris_2_Data$CH4 <- as.numeric(Aeris_2_Data$CH4)
Aeris_2_Data$Date.Time <- as.POSIXct(Aeris_2_Data$Time_Stamp, tz = "", "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")

ggplot(Aeris_2_Data, aes(x = Date.Time, y = as.numeric(CH4))) + geom_point() + labs(x = "Time", y = "CH4 [ppm]") + ggtitle("Methane Over Time")
```